# Printing the values in the AH, AL, BH, and BL registers in assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I want to create a procedure that prints the values of the `AH`, `AL`, `BH`, and `BL` registers. I have this:

```
prntABHL:
    PUSH    BL
    PUSH    BH
    PUSH    AL
    PUSH    AH
    PUSH    fourNums  ! defined in data as "%d, %d, %d, %d\n"
    PUSH    _PRINTF
    SYS
    ADD SP, 12        ! reset stack
    RET
```

This causes four register errors on the `PUSH` instructions. I assume because `PUSH` expects a 16-bit value, and `AH` and `AL` are 8-bit values.

How can I specify the values in the `AH`, `AL`, `BH`, and `BL` registers as arguments to a function if they are not 16-bits long? Is there a reasonably straightforward way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to push the values of 8-bit registers as 16-bit values, it's easy if you have eg. `cx` or any other 16-bit general register (`cx`, `dx`, `bp`, `si`, `di`) free to use:

Edit: **movzx** is not available on pre-386 processors. Replaced with 8088/8086 instructions.

```
xor   cx, cx
mov   cl, bl
push  cx
mov   cl, bh
push  cx
mov   cl, al
push  cx
mov   cl, ah
push  cx
```

If you don't have 16-bit general register free to use, you have to save the save the value to be pushed somewhere else and push it to stack from there.

Comment: I get an error message `Register error` on the lines that do `MOV CL, BL`, and the others that move something to CL. Do you have any idea what could cause that? They have matching lengths.

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: 8088/8086 is an instruction set, as are 286, 386, 486 etc. Assembler is the program (eg. NASM, GAS,  TASM, MASM, A86, A386 etc.) used to **assemble** the source code to a binary file (eg. `.com`). So what program (assembler) you are using?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using this [academic assembler toolkit](http://sun-java.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~robd/courses/2007/comp202/materials/cdrom/html/8088_tra/linux.htm) designed for educational use, rather than something built for actual developers.

Comment: It's not very educational, as the 286 replaced the 8088 in the year 1982 A.D. (I was there). It would be much better to learn something from this millennium, like 64-bit assembly.

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure MOVZX is present on pre-386. Second, good old 8086 is often used, for instance, for teaching students on how to make calculations with 32-64 bits when some has to implement division algortihm himself, take care of carry on add/sub etc.

Comment: @AlekseyIvchenko You're right, `movzx` is available only from 386 onwards http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/movzx.html . Answer edited accordingly. For teaching purposes 8086 might be fine, but for learning assembly for real use I'd suggest go straight to x86-64 (or 32-bit x86 if one doesn't have a 64-bit OS installed).